# Python Orator ORM only creates a model through save method

Tags: python

I was hoping someone could explain to me why the `create` method isn't creating a record in the database but if I instantiate the model then `save` it then it will persist in the database.

when using the create method I get the following error.

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'postcode'`

```py
# Not working
location = Location.create(postcode="TS1 3ST")

# Working
location = Location()
location.postcode = "TS1 3ST"
location.save()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As of version .09:
As states in the documentation

> You can also use the create method to save a model in a single line,
>   but you will need to specify either the fillable or guarded property
>   on the model since all models are protected against mass-assignment by
>   default.

In your model you must add:

```
class Location(Model):
    __fillable__ = ['postcode']
```

Reference:
https://github.com/sdispater/orator/issues/302: